# Rust use Postgres JSON attribute: cannot convert between the Rust type `alloc::string::String` and the Postgres type `jsonb`

Tags: json, postgresql, rust, rust-tokio

Currently I am able to use the following code, but I do not want to have to cast my JSON to text in my postgres query since it adds latency.

```
async fn filter_data(min : f32, max : f32, pool: &Pool) -> Result<String, PoolError> {
    let client: Client = pool.get().await?;
    let sql = format!("select \"json\"::TEXT from get_data({}, {})", min, max);
    let stmt = client.prepare(&sql).await?;
    let rows = client.query(&stmt, &[]).await?;
    Ok(rows[0].get(0))
}
```

If I do not cast my JSON to text, I get the following error:

```
error retrieving column 0: error deserializing column 0: cannot convert between the Rust type `alloc::string::String` and the Postgres type `jsonb`
```

What type can be used so that I return that json value without casting it to text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use Json and Jsonb values, you need to enable the feature in the postgres create with
`features = ["with-serde_json-1"]`

And then you can change your return type to be `Result<serde_json::Value,PoolError>`

so you would have in your cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
postgres = {version = "0.17.3" , features = ["with-serde_json-1"] }
serde_json = "1.0.56"
```

and in your main.rs

```
async fn reverse_geocode(min : f32, max : f32, pool: &Pool) -> Result<serde_json::Value, PoolError> {
    let client: Client = pool.get().await?;
    let sql = format!("select \"json\" from get_data({}, {})", min, max);
    let stmt = client.prepare(&sql).await?;
    let rows = client.query(&stmt, &[]).await?;
    Ok(rows[0].get(0))
}
```

Comment: Finally! I was missing the serde_json::Value type from my struct. Thanks